# Need to display list with brackets and comma removed

Tags: python, list, printing

I need help solving an issue with my assignment, I am not asking for anyone to complete the coding for the entire assignment. I just would like some input on why my current code is not working properly. I am new to Python and about two months into my course. My current code is as follows:

```
import random
values =[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
COLS = 7

def main():
    for c in range(COLS):
        values[c] = random.randint(19, 81)        
    outfile = open('nums.txt', 'w')
    outfile.write(str(values))
    outfile.close


    infile=open('nums.txt', 'r')
    numbers = infile.readlines()
    index = 0

    while index>len(numbers):
        numbers[index]=int(numbers[index])
        index += 1

    print(numbers)

main()
```

When the code is supposed to output the numbers from the list, it only prints `[]` (empty brackets). I need it to display the list of 7 numbers without brackets or commas on one line.

This is the assignment if it helps:
In the main function:

Create an empty list named nums.
Use a loop (type of your own choosing) to add seven integers, each in the range 20 to 80, to nums. Duplicates are okay.
Use a second loop to display the seven integers all on one line separated by a single space. This second loop must be a while loop.
Display the largest integer in the list.
Display the smallest integer in the list.
Call a void function named process that takes a slice made from nums as an argument. This slice should be missing the first and last elements of nums.

In the process function:

Display the elements in the slice all on one line separated by a single space and sorted in highest to lowest order.
You must use a for loop in process. The elements should NOT be displayed inside [ ] separated by commas.

```
Example Output
79 30 39 33 41 43 53
The highest number is 79
The lowest number is 30
The middle 5 sorted high to low:
43 41 39 33 30
```

As I said before, I am not requesting anyone to complete the assignment for me, I would just like help fixing my code up to this point. I have read through this site many times when I hit roadblocks and just cannot figure this one out.

Comment: Why the file operation, may I ask? I didn't see any requirements of reading and writing files.

Comment: "Need to display list with brackets and comma removed" [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Comment: The file operation was a careless mistake. I mixed up last week with this assignment.

Answer (score 0):

your loop condition is wrong:

```
while index>len(numbers):
```

should be:

```
while index<len(numbers):
```

to print the list you can use the str.join() function:

```
print ' '.join(numbers)
```

Comment: I actually had the original text as "while index<len(numbers)". When I was messing with the code trying to figure out why it wasn't working, I had flipped it around and didn't change it back before saving. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't know why you need to write the data into file, but you are doing it wrong. You made a careless mistake and didn't close the file properly. You should use:

```
outfile.close()
```

Next, you are writing the python expr of the array into the file, which is kind of wrong, too. I think it's better to do this:

```
for v in values:
    outfile.write(str(v) + '\n')
outfile.close()
```

And while reading the file, like yurib suggested, you should use:

```
while index<len(numbers):
    numbers[index]=int(numbers[index])
    index += 1
```

Again, I don't know why the file operation. But now it finally works

Comment: The file operation was a careless mistake from mixing up last week with this assignment. I ended up writing the program over and it is fully operational. This is the new program: